# How do I select out a date in a certain format?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a column in a table, with certain dates entered by users in the incorrect format.
They should be in `YYYYMMDD`, instead some have been wrongly entered as `DDMMYYYY`.

What is the best way for me to quickly grab these out?
Thanks.

Comment: The best way is to declare the column to be a `datetime` value, so you never have this problem.

Comment: Thanks - this is 1 small part of a larger query, and i was wondering if there is a quick and simple way I can select the date out in this particular (incorrect) way on the fly?

Comment: How do you know it is DDMMYYYY and not MMDDYYYY? Could it be both? e.g. 08092014 could be either (there is an ambiguity area it is impossible to the distinguish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brute force for this.  I don't know if Sybase understands `DDMMYYYY` as a format, but you can do something like:

```
select convert(datetime,
               (case when col like '____19%' or col like '____20%'
                     then right(col, 4) + substring(col, 3, 2) + left(col, 2)
                     else col
                end),
               112)
```